# Can I deploy two different services (Java and NodeJs) using Docker?

Tags: docker

I have two services, one developed in Java and the other one in nodejs. Can I deploy these on windows OS? Is it possible to deploy services in distributed mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can deploy both the technologies on different containers. That's the beauty of Docker/Containerization.

Create both the images from a base image from [Docker Hub](http://hub.docker.com) and build upon the base image and create a new image. Use the new image for deployment. Upload the new image on Docker Hub and then you can pull it from Docker on any Windows OS and run it.

However, I suggest you run the containers on any Linux distribution as the container can use many a files/binaries from the host OS which will thereby reduce the resources consumed by the containers.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can different services running on different machines (distributed mode) be managed by docker as a single package?